# Jquery callback function on animate

Tags: jquery-animate

I figured out how to do a callback function for this type jquery animate method

```
$("#div1").animate({top: "-=100"}, 2000, function(){alert("hi")});
```

But I cant seem to figure out how to make a simple alert callback function with this animate() function.

```
$('#div1').animate({top: "-800"}, {duration: 3000}).animate({left: "-700"}, 
{duration: 3000, queue: false});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#div1')
.animate({top: "-800"}, {duration: 3000})
.animate({left: "-700"}, {duration: 3000, queue: false, complete: function() {console.log('done');}});
```

in this case, the the callback function must be part of the options object, like complete: function() { // code here }